# Exact pattern match for Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am creating a python program to evaluate a user entered expression f(x) in terms of x and any numbers and mathematical operations. I want to match my regular expression to validate the string entered by the user.

It **must** contain an 'x'.
It may or may not contain any of the numbers, mathematical operators like +,-,*,/ and a decimal point '.'

example 1+x**2 is valid but 1+x+y is not (since there is a 'y')
please help me with the regex expression. So far I have `[x0-9\.\+\-\*\/]+`

Comment: Anchor the regexp so the whole string has to match.

Comment: How do I anchor the regex?

Comment: `^` anchors to the beginning, `$` anchors to the end. Any tutorial should explain this.